# Using LINQ to join [n] collections and find matches

Tags: linq, collections, recursion

Using LINQ I can find matching elements between two collections like this:

```
        var alpha = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        var beta = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 5 };

        return (from a in alpha
                join b in beta on a equals b
                select a);
```

I can increased this to three collections, like so:

```
        var alpha = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        var beta = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 5 };
        var gamma = new List<int>() { 3 };

        return (from a in alpha
                join b in beta on a equals b
                join g in gamma on a equals g
                select a);
```

But how can I construct **a LINQ query that will return the matches between N number of collections?**

I'm thinking if each collection was added to a parent collection, then the parent collection was iterated through using a recursive loop, it may work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to recurse - you can just iterate. However, you may find it best to create a set and intersect *that* each time:

```
List<List<int>> collections = ...;

HashSet<int> values = new HashSet<int>(collections[0]);
foreach (var collection in collections.Skip(1)) // Already done the first
{
    values.IntersectWith(collection);
}
```

(Like BrokenGlass, I'm assuming you've got distint values, and that you *really* just want to find the values which are in all the collections.)

If you prefer the immutable and lazy approach, you could use:

```
List<List<int>> collections = ...;

IEnumerable<int> values = collections[0];
foreach (var collection in collections.Skip(1)) // Already done the first
{
    values = values.Intersect(collection);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only unique values you can use Intersect:

```
var result = alpha.Intersect(beta).Intersect(gamma).ToList();
```

If you need to preserve multiple values that are not unique you can just exclude non-intersecting items from the original collection as an additional step:

```
alpha = alpha.Where(x => result.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

To generalize the Intersect approach you can just use a loop to do all intersections one by one:

```
IEnumerable<List<int>> collections = new [] { alpha, beta, gamma };
IEnumerable<int> result = collections.First();
foreach (var item in collections.Skip(1))
{
    result = result.Intersect(item);
}
result = result.ToList();
```